# How insert PHP output into html div replacing temp graphic

Tags: php, javascript, html, innerhtml

I need to display an html page and within the page is a div  into which I want to echo the output of a PHP page.

While the PHP page is being fetched and prepared I want to display a "Loading" msg and a temporary gif.

I have the html code working
and I have the PHP code working/echo'ing.

How do I echo the contents of the PHP page to replace the original contents of the Div.? 
(I guess - with an include:file and an innerhtml statement, but how/where?)

A Javascript solution would be fine.

Thanks

Comment: A JavaScript solution is the *only* solution. Look into jQuery's `.get` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're essentially looking to make an asynchoronous call to your php script once the page is loading, so JavaScript is your friend.

When the page loads, include the loading message and the temporary gif, then do an ajax call to your php script and insert the response into the relevant div.

As @Sjoerd points out - jQuery will do this for you nicely.

Answer (score 4):

Add a div to your page with the image in it, then using [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

```
 $('#myDiv').load('mypage.php');
```

Comment: I've include a jquery libary:

Answer (score 0):

take a look into ajax:

[The Low-down](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29)

[Using ajax with jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: I've added a jquery libary: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script> and created a javascript function as follows: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script> Which is called onload: <body onload="loadFB"> And I have a Div as follows: 

<div class="facebookfeed" style="position:relative">
 <h4>Loading...  <img src="images/fb_loader.gif" width="32" height="32"/></h4>
</div>

But it's not working - could you help me further
@Sjoerd
@Gary Barnett

Comment: Typo's in previous post:  Shaould have read:
I've added a jquery libary: <script type="text/javascript" src="ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/…; 
and created a javascript function as follows: 
function loadFB(){
 $('facebookfeed').load('Untitled_1.php');
}

Which is called onload: 
<body onload="loadFB"> 
And I have a Div as follows: <div id="facebookfeed"><h4>Loading... <img src="images/fb_loader.gif" width="32" height="32"/></h4> </div> 
But it's not working - could you help me further @Sjoerd @Gary Barnett

Comment: Got it working now. I was missing an "#" at the front of "facebookfeed"
Thanks for all your help.